# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger

Tags: java, jetty, bots, classnotfoundexception, discord

Hey guys i am beginner in Java programming and i am making a DiscordBot for my Discord server. Code is all right i was following the tutorial but when i try to start the program i get this error:

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger"

My code looks like this:

```
public static final IDiscordClient bot = createClient("your_token", true);

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(bot.getApplicationClientID());
}

public static IDiscordClient createClient(String token, boolean login)
{
    ClientBuilder clientBuilder = new ClientBuilder();
    clientBuilder.withToken(token);
    try
    {
        if (login)
        {
            return clientBuilder.login();
        }
        else
        {
            return clientBuilder.build();
        }
    }
    catch (DiscordException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand what `ClassNotFoundException` means?

Comment: I understand i think but in that tutorial it worked for the guy and he didnt upload any jar file to classpath only to modulepath and i did that also. I really dont know how to fix this. Should i just download that jar file from google or?

Comment: Are you using eclipse embedded jetty server ?

Comment: Seems like you are just missing the jetty-util.jar for that same version of Jetty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys i am idiot i just downloaded lightweight jar that didnt include everything i needed. I downloaded full jar file and its ok now.